# Negative lookahead alternative for bigquery

Tags: regex, google-bigquery, regex-lookarounds

I'm using `REGEXP_CONTAINS` of Big query and want to implement it for pattern

```js
^[-]?(?!0\d)\d*.?\d*$
```

But Big Query doesn't support Negative Lookahead and hence I'm looking for alternative of above pattern which is supported by Big Query.
Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: It is not quite clear. Did you use `.` to match a literal `.` char or also a comma, and any other char? Try `^\-?(?:(?:[1-9]\d*|0)(?:[.,]\d*)?|[.,]\d+)$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cay3iH/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the `.` in my regex is decimal point which we give in decimal number. Thanks!

Comment: I guess I should had escaped it with backslash `\.` to match it with decimal point

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to asserting not zero would be to just assert one through nine:

```
^-?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d+)?$
```

Your phrasing of an optional decimal component also needed a refactor.  The above pattern is matching either an integer or decimal number which does not begin with zero.